# datatable append html but got refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Not sure what is wrong, for me my code has the right logic. But somehow the html didn't stay after 2nd click onward. I expect my custom html would appear after the newly added `tr`.

my function

```
function appendRow(name, position, office, age, date,salary) {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    var node = t.row.add([
      name,
      position,
      office,
      age,
      date,
      salary,
    ]).draw().node();

    var detail_row = '';

    detail_row = '<h3>Custom HTML</h3>';

    $(node).addClass('result-row');

    node = node.outerHTML += detail_row;

    $(node).hide().fadeIn('normal');
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/282w8yfk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happening in this way because you applied sorting on the name column, so datatable being quite smart it adds the row where it needs to be... so if you want to add that in the last remove sorting option on name column...

and here is a small code change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
  function format(d) {
    console.log(d);
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Name:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d[0] + '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Full Name:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d[4] + '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
      '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</table>';
  }

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [4],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
      }]
      /* the problem is here, it won't work if I enable sorting*/
  });

  function appendRow() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    var node = t.row.add([
      "James Bond",
      "Spy", "55", "$9000", "James Bond Larry"
    ]).draw().node();

    console.log(node);
    $(node).addClass('result-row').hide().fadeIn('normal');
  };

  $('#add').click(function() {
    appendRow();
  });

  $('#example tbody').on('click', '.result-row', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
});
```

[reference 1 - sort](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bSort)

[reference 2 - row.add](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

Comment: I checked ur fiddle, and that's not what I want, I didn't see what's the different of my with urs. I expect the custom html stay in every newly added `tr`.

Comment: I checked ur fiddle, and that's not what I want, I didn't see what's the different of my with urs. I expect the custom html stay in every newly added `tr`.

Comment: Okay for custom html need to look, i solved a problem of appendong new items at the end.. I will look at kt later on, as i am away from my pc now

Comment: var table = $('#example').DataTable({ "bSort": false });  ........... Is the only difference, and see the explanation so you will get it what it does... @Kian Phin

Comment: @JamieJordan : Actually the draw method always redraws the table, so it removes your old inserted elements, and redraws your view again...

Comment: @ParagBhayani so what should I do?

Comment: @JamieJordan : I was  looking at option of having custom row renderer but I couldn't find any ...

Comment: @JamieJordan : There is another feature of child row render, You would like to give a try on it -> https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html  I am not able to try this at the moment ...

Comment: Probably you can use events like drawcallback https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback   ... when draw is completed you go through all rows and append custom HTML to every node .... To go through every rows -> var api = this.api(); and then api.rows has every rows .....

Comment: I also tried create row callback it wasn't useful for our case -> https://jsfiddle.net/282w8yfk/5/ but you might get idea of how to use it with drawCallBack

Comment: @ParagBhayani I solved that issue. but now I'm facing another issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240604/datatables-sorting-ruined-child-rows

Comment: @JamieJordan: Okay looking into it, if this answer is appropriate then you can upvote and accept answer

Comment: @JamieJordan : Hey I have updated an answer and I think it completely answers your question... Have a look at it..