# Datatables sorting ruined child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Not sure how I solve this issue, tried 2 days couldn't solve it. I want to prepend using add method but the sorting is running it by sorting hidden row too. The hidden row act as child row which give the parent row more information. I must make the sorting work otherwise I couldn't do prepend.

try to uncomment the "bSort":false then you will see the broken version.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    /* the problem is here, it won't work if I enable sorting*/
  });
```

Working version

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    /* the problem is here, it won't work if I enable sorting*/
  });
  
  function appendRow() {
            var t = $('#example').DataTable();                        
           
            var node = t.row.add([
                "James Bond",
              "Spy","55","$9000"
                ]).node();

            var node2 = t.row.add([
              "<p>Full Name: James Bond Larry</p>",
                null,
                null,
                null
                ]).draw().node();

            $(node2).addClass('detail-row hide');
                
            $(node).addClass('result-row').hide().fadeIn('normal');
        };
  
  $('#add').click(function(){
    appendRow();
  });
  
  $('#example tbody').on('click','.result-row',function(){
            var tr = $(this).next('.detail-row');
            if(tr.hasClass('hide')){
                tr.removeClass('hide');
            }else{
                tr.addClass('hide');
            }
        });
  
} );
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody>
          <tr class="result-row">
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="detail-row hide">
            <td><p>Full Name: Tiger Nikola Nixon</p></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div id="add"><button>Add row</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you create fiddle for this

Comment: When you are facing an issue? when bSort: is false or true?

Comment: Here adding two rows isn't the correct approach, it is going to ruin things internally if sorting is true..

Comment: @ParagBhayani at least creating 2 rows achieved what I want earlier. If not what would be the approach?

Comment: @ParagBhayani https://jsfiddle.net/ae4nbz8w/

Comment: Okay looking into it...

Comment: @Jamir Jordan: See the answer

Answer (score 0):

it is happening in this way because you applied sorting on the name column, so datatable being quite smart it adds the row where it needs to be... so if you want to add that in the last remove sorting option on name column...

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/ae4nbz8w/1/) which does following things

Here I have added one hidden column with below config

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": [ 4 ],// Hide 4th column
  "visible": false,
  "searchable": false
}]
```

You can write anything in format function to have any specific view aswell here I have added a table with 3 rows, but you can customize it

Here I have adding extra rows for every addrows as we have discussed earlier, but here I am adding a row when user clicks on the row, you can see click function how it works..

and here is a small code change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
  function format(d) {
    console.log(d);
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Name:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d[0] + '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Full Name:</td>' +
      '<td>' + d[4] + '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
      '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</table>';
  }

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [4],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
      }]
      /* the problem is here, it won't work if I enable sorting*/
  });

  function appendRow() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    var node = t.row.add([
      "James Bond",
      "Spy", "55", "$9000", "James Bond Larry"
    ]).draw().node();

    console.log(node);
    $(node).addClass('result-row').hide().fadeIn('normal');
  };

  $('#add').click(function() {
    appendRow();
  });

  $('#example tbody').on('click', '.result-row', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
});
```

[reference 1 - sort](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bSort)

[reference 2 - row.add](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

[referece 3 - Adding row on click](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)